# How to configure <Context> in a multi instance Tomcat if the application folder name is different from the context name?

Tags: java, tomcat

My setup:
OS - macOS Catalina
Tomcat v9.0.20

```
$CATALINA_HOME - /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.20
$CATALINA_BASE - /usr/local/tomcat_instance/idev
```

Instance's $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8205" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    
    <Connector port="8280" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="8443" />
    
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    </Host>
    
</Server>
```

The application is a Java/SpringBoot app deployed as exploded folder (not .war file).

App's deployment folder - `/usr/local/tomcat_instance/idev/webapps/handbook-server.`

```
application.properties
    server.servlet.context-path=/handbook
```

I would like my app to have a context of /handbook so I can access it like so:
http://localhost:8280/handbook

My app's context file $CATALINA_BASE/conf/handbook.xml

```
<Context
    docBase="/handbook-server" 
    path="/handbook" 
    reloadable="true" 
/>
```

After looking at some similar questions here in SO, I have tried setting docBase as follows:

1. docBase="/handbook-server"
2. docBase="handbook-server"
3. docBase="handbook-server"
4. docBase="/usr/local/tomcat_instance/idev/webapps/handbook-server"

All of the above docBase settings DID NOT work.

The application works if I access it as http://localhost:8280/handbook-server

What is the correct way of setting the docBase value?
Any answer and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the following work:

1. Created a folder to hold the context definition in
   $CATALINA_BASE/idev/conf/Catalina/localhost
2. Created $CATALINA_BASE/idev/conf/Catalina/localhost/handbook.xml

   ```
   <Context
       docBase="../apps/handbook-server" 
       path="/handbook" 
       reloadable="true"/>
   ```
3. Created the app's deployment folder outside of webapps folder `$CATALINA_BASE/idev/apps/handbook-server`

To access the app, I point the browser to http://localhost:8280/handbook

If somebody have a solution where the app is placed inside webapps, I would appreciate it if you can post the it.